# Use XAMPP mysql for IIS 8

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, iis-8

Xampp installed on my pc and working fine. I have to run php on IIS-8. I installed PHP for IIS-8. It is working fine. Now i have to use MySql for database task. Mysql is already installed in Xampp.

How I configured Mysql for IIS-8.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message? Your IIS install of PHP should be able to see MySQL (provided you point it to the correct IP address or named pipe, which is no different than with XAMPP).

Comment: Thank @IsaacBennetch its to late but i uninstall xampp with all mysql event and download mysql and phpmyadmin for iis8 now it is working fine . i will rnd about it letter Thanks